# how to get the input and final output of a pytorch network

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

is there an API of how to get the intput and output node of a pytorch network ?
I tried model.features(), but this won't help.

---

Example: I get a pytorch network, and its structure in netron:
[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8fcq.png)

The Conv2d, MaxPool2d and Linear can be easily parsed. I get trouble with getting the information like name and size of the input node and output node.

Comment: What do you mean "get the by input and output of a network"? Can you give an example? Do you want to get the weights of those layers?

Comment: @ nsidn98 Example: I get a pytorch network, and its structure in netron: network

The Conv2d, MaxPool2d and Linear can be easily parsed. I get trouble with getting the information like name and size of the input node and output node.

Answer (score 0):

For getting input to a particular layer means output of previous layer.

So for getting any information during forward pass and backward pass like output of a specific layer, gradient, or if you want to modify any of them there is concept in pytorch known as **Hooks**.

Find more information here https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html#forward-and-backward-function-hooks